# Linux Mint not detected

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I dual-booted Linux Mint and Windows 10 on my computer this morning. It was going fine until I rebooted the computer. Windows 10 booted straight in instead of Linux. I checked the BIOS for an entry like Linux or Grub but there was just Windows Boot Manager and DVD-RW.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install first Windows 10, then install your Linux distro, also disable the UEFI system to regular BOOT B.I.O.S, otherwise Windows will "eat" the others O.S on the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool that I use a lot, and which I used for my own Win10 + Linux Mint dual boot.

This tool is called [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) (use the free version, I never got spam from them) and it allows you to completly configure Windows bootloader.

If you use it, remember to uncheck the box "Use Metro bootloader", because it slows down your boot a lot when you want to boot with Linux.

Comment: https://virustotal.com/fr/file/df7801b556bcf2839a891783ac13817a032ec520372eafdceb7aa35196c0e9b0/analysis/1468843877/

Comment: If the file you downloaded doesn't give the same result (or doesn't have the same SHA-256), try a google search.

Comment: The SHA-256 is displayed when you upload the file to VirusTotal. You should be able to download it from other websites, the top result when I google it is Clubic...

Comment: The you have to disable UEFI from your BIOS settings. When your computer boots, mash the key to open the BIOS settings (depends on your computer brand, often F2 or F12) and find the settings that corresponds to UEFI (usually in a "Boot" tab).